# SharePoint 2010 - Change order of User Profile properties

Tags: user-profile, object-model

I would like to know how to change the display order of the out of the box user profile properties using sharepoint object model ?

I would like to move OOTB properties into my custom section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [Property Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.property.aspx)

> There are two types of user profile properties:
>
> Regular - Defines the property data type and the corresponding user
>   profile flags.
>
> Section  - Property that serves as a separator for user interface
>   grouping purposes.

**In order to move properties 'into' section you just need to reorder them.**

I am providing a little example on how to create new section and then move few OOTB properties 'into' it by simple reorder. Check code comments for clarification.

```
var customSectionDisplayName = "My New CustomSection";
// For 'internal' name remove whitespace
var customSectionName = customSectionDisplayName.Replace(" ", "");

using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://mycoolsite"))
{
    SPServiceContext context = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
    // There are just 'few' managers we need
    UserProfileConfigManager upcm = new UserProfileConfigManager(context);
    ProfilePropertyManager ppm = upcm.ProfilePropertyManager;
    CorePropertyManager cpm = ppm.GetCoreProperties();
    ProfileTypePropertyManager ptpm = ppm.GetProfileTypeProperties(ProfileType.User);
    ProfileSubtypeManager psm = ProfileSubtypeManager.Get(context);
    ProfileSubtype ps = psm.GetProfileSubtype(ProfileSubtypeManager.GetDefaultProfileName(ProfileType.User));
    ProfileSubtypePropertyManager pspm = ps.Properties;

    // Check if section already exist
    if(cpm.GetSectionByName(customSectionName) == null)
    {
        // Add new section
        CoreProperty section = cpm.Create(true);
        section.Name = customSectionName;
        section.DisplayName = customSectionDisplayName;
        section.Commit();
        ProfileTypeProperty profileSection = ptpm.Create(section);
        profileSection.Commit();
        ProfileSubtypeProperty profileSubSection = pspm.Create(profileSection);
        profileSubSection.DefaultPrivacy = Privacy.Private;
        profileSubSection.Commit();
    }

    // In default configuration Custom Properties are the last section 
    // with display order value of 5500
    // Let's move our new section to the end
    pspm.SetDisplayOrderBySectionName(customSectionName, 6000);
    pspm.CommitDisplayOrder();

    // And now let's move some core properties 
    // Work Email ...
    pspm.SetDisplayOrderByPropertyName(PropertyConstants.WorkEmail, 6100);
    // ... and Work Phone 
    pspm.SetDisplayOrderByPropertyName(PropertyConstants.WorkPhone, 6200);
    pspm.CommitDisplayOrder();
}
```