# Change order of user profile property

Tags: client-object-model, user-profile-property

Hi i want to change the order of user profile property in a subtype i found out this link [SharePoint 2010 - Change order of User Profile properties](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19474/sharepoint-2010-change-order-of-user-profile-properties)  which is changing only in default sub type but its not changing in other sub types .Can anyone suggest me how to achieve that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to change the line:

```
ProfileSubtype ps = psm.GetProfileSubtype(ProfileSubtypeManager.GetDefaultProfileName(ProfileType.User));
```

to

```
ProfileSubtype ps = psm.GetProfileSubtype("MySubTypeName");
```